# Regular front road wheel for a single speed bike

Tags: wheels, single-speed

I recently crashed my Kona Paddy Wagon ruining the front wheel completely. All the single-speed/fixed-wheel dedicated wheels I was able to find are crap, and I don't want to spend too much time purchasing individual components and having someone build a wheel for me.

I was thinking of buying a standard road front wheel with a skewer and QR. I assume that would work as long as the O.L.D. is correct (100 mm in my case)?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you looking?  There are all kinds of online places to buy decent bicycle wheels of all types.  Maybe look at track wheels - they're likely to be of higher quality than wheels sold as single-speed/fixie wheels.

Comment: Any 100mm front wheel will fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a 'single speed specific front wheel'. I think what you mean is you are looking for a front wheel with a threaded axle that is fixed in the fork with nuts, rather than a quick release. Such wheels are used on inexpensive department-store type bikes as well as quality single speed or fixed gear machines.

My guess is that you are finding replacement wheels aimed at the former type of bike which will will indeed be cheap and heavy. As Andrew Henle said in a comment look for track wheels. Also look for SS/fixie specific online stores.

Update:

<strike>You may have a problem with a quick release hub wheel as (I believe) threaded axles are 10mm diameter whereas front QR axles are 9mm and will move in the 10mm wide dropouts.</strike>

Front threaded axles are SAE 3/8" x 24tpi which is 9.6mm outside diameter.

Comment: Any source for front bolt on axle being 10mm? As far as I know it's 9mm and interchangeable with QR. Paddy Wagon is by the way incredibly heavy even if it wasn't the cheapest fixie at the time.

Comment: It is a bit of a tank, but after 9 years of use I can say that it's very reliable and takes all kinds of commuting abuse very well.